# Mysql How to join 2 tables and 1 table itself

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table name `tbl_user` this table contain

```
db_uid   db_fname   db_lname   db_responsibleid     db_email
  1         xxx       yyy            0             xxx@x.com
  2         ttt       eee            1             ttt@x.com
  3         ggg       hhh            2             ggg@x.com
```

The other table is `tbl_task` this table contain

```
db_taskid    db_mytask    db_desc   db_status   db_emailed   db_userid
   1           test       test        Done          0           2
   2           bnvc       sdcs        Done          0           3
   3           bcv        sdc         Scheduled     0           3
```

**Now i want to have this result:**

```
  taskid   mytask   desc   Status   staffname   responsiblename    remail
    1       test    test   Done      ttt eee      xxx yyy        xxx@x.com
    2       bnvc    sdcs   Done      ggg hhh      ttt eee        ttt$x.com
```

this result to select all task that have `db_status='Done'` and `db_emailed='0'`
with the name of the user and the name of the responsible of that user with the email of the responsible

I use this query but i can't get the name of the responsible and his email address

```
select 
    tbl_task.db_mytask,
    tbl_task.db_desc,
    tbl_task.db_taskid,
    tbl_task.db_status,
    concat(tbl_user.db_fname,' ' ,tbl_user.db_lname) as name,
    concat(user.db_fname,' ' ,user.db_lname) as uname,
    user.db_email
from tbl_task 
left join tbl_user
    on tbl_task.db_userid=tbl_user.db_uid
left join tbl_user as user
    on user.db_uid=user.db_responsibleid
where 
    (tbl_task.db_emailed='0') 
    and 
    (tbl_task.db_status='Done')
```

**Current result is:**

```
taskid   mytask   desc   Status   staffname   responsiblename    remail
  1       test    test   Done      ttt eee        NULL             NULL
  2       bnvc    sdcs   Done      ggg hhh        NULL             NULL
```

How can i solve this problem any suggestion or help ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You join the wrong columns on the second left join  (i have use user1 and use2 alias for the two join on tbl_user)

you use `user.db_uid=user.db_responsibleid`  but should `tbl_user.db_uid=user.db_responsibleid`

```
  select 
    tbl_task.db_mytask,
    tbl_task.db_desc,
    tbl_task.db_taskid,
    tbl_task.db_status,
    concat(user1.db_fname,' ' ,user1.db_lname) as name,
    concat(user2.db_fname,' ' ,user2.db_lname) as uname,
    user2.db_email
  from tbl_task 
  left join tbl_user as user1 on tbl_task.db_userid=user1.db_uid
  left join tbl_user as user2 on user2.db_uid=user1.db_responsibleid
  where tbl_task.db_emailed='0'
  and tbl_task.db_status='Done'
```

Comment: i have the same result of my current result posted above i don't have the responsible name and his email

Comment: Answer  updated .. Inverted join tables on second left join

Answer (score 2):

You can try this query.
Check if it meets your requirements

```
select
    tbl_task.db_taskid,
    tbl_task.db_mytask as mytask, 
    tbl_task.db_desc,    
    tbl_task.db_status,
    concat(tbl_user.db_fname,' ' ,tbl_user.db_lname) as name,
    concat(users.db_fname,' ' ,users.db_lname) as responsiblename, 
    users.db_email as remail
from tbl_user AS users 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN tbl_user ON users.db_uid = tbl_user.db_responsibleid 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN tbl_task ON tbl_user.db_uid = tbl_task.db_userid
where  (tbl_task.db_emailed='0') and (tbl_task.db_status='Done')
```